# angular2 material access tab values

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular2-material

I have the following code:

```
<md-tab-group (selectChange)="doSomething()">
  <md-tab *ngFor="let p of something))">
    <template md-tab-label>
     {{p.name}} ...
    </template>
   </md-tab>
 </md-tab-group>
```

Now doSomething() get's fired on Tab-Change and I can access the selected Index, but is there any way to access values of my *ngFor loop? I'd need 'p.id' in my code to fetch data from my database, depending on the open tab.
Or is there a much more elegant solution I am not thinking of?  Thanks for any help :)

Comment: How do you need to fetch data from your database?

Comment: just via angular2's http .. but that's not important right here. I just wanted to clarify, that I need to access a tab's template variable from outer md-tab-group .

Comment: How do you want to access it?

Comment: Inside my doSometing() function. I need to fetch different data depending on what tab is shown, but what data i need is dependend on what "p" element is selected (that is I don't know which one depending on tab-index)

Comment: How one is dependent on tab-index?

Comment: I mean it's not dependend on tab index.... i don't know what data to load by looking at the tab index. i need my p element

Comment: Can you provide a plunk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested, I solved my problem this way:

1. Add an data-attrib to the tab generated by *ngFor and pass the whole tabgroup to my function:

> ```
> <md-tab-group #tabgroup (selectChange)="doSomething(tabgroup)">
>           <md-tab *ngFor="let p of something" [attr.data-pid]="p.id">
>             <template md-tab-label>
>              {{p.name}} ...
>             </template>
>            </md-tab>
>          </md-tab-group>
> ```

2. Get my selected md-tab, with it my nativeElement, and from that get my data-attrib. Not nice & clean, but it works.

> ```
> doSomething(tabgroup: MdTabGroup) {
>
>         let pid = tabgroup._tabs.find((e, i, a) => i == tabgroup.selectedIndex)
>             .content.viewContainerRef.element.nativeElement.dataset.pid;
>
>         console.log(pid);
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by sending in the $event to the function

```
<md-tab-group #tabs (selectChange)="myFunction($event)">
    <md-tab label="My label" data-my-value="123">
        ...
    </md-tab>
    ...
</md-tab-group>
```

And then getting the value from that object

```
myFunction($event: any) {
    let myValue = $event.tab.content.viewContainerRef.element.nativeElement.getAttribute('data-my-value');
}
```